# Ajax requests start failing after 10+ requests

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

I am writing an iOS PhoneGap app. I have plenty of code that loads data using the jQuery $.get() method. I use the same technique to load some fragments of html from my local app directory. Meaning, as I navigate from page to page, I request the HTML content using $.get(). All good so far.

The problem is that shortly into playing around with my app (testing on Safari), all ajax calls start failing. The error message I get is:

> Failed to load resource: The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 1.)

I don't get it to work unless I completely refresh the page. Has anyone seen this before?